# Flying to Europe with Private Mobile Radio

Tags: air-travel, legal, hand-luggage, electronic-items, austria

We are going to make a trip to Austria and wanted to take small radio-stations (Private Mobile Radio) with us to communicate in mountains.

We had only hand luggage in our tickets. So, is it allowed to bring such devices to airplane within hand luggage?

Comment: I doubt the airline cares provided the devices are turned off. You should check whether you can use them in Austria, though.

Comment: Exactly what radios do you have? From what country? On what frequencies do they operate?

Comment: We have simple walkie-talkies [Voxtel MR950](https://c.dns-shop.ru/thumb/st4/fit/800/650/b0c74cd16a8303e29ae3e1ae58b4349b/d23d4adfb21f3b472bfa8565172b5730a32e76033c4a7008fa238b1130d49e1e.jpg) that are operates at 446.0-446.1 MHz. Those things were bought  at Ukraine where this stuff doesn't require any licenses.

Comment: Yes, those are OK to use in the EU. But they [should not be used in the US](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/5174/2643).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking the radios won't be a problem.  Using them in Austria is highly likely to be a problem, unless your radios operate on a radio spectrum permitted for similar use in both countries.

For example, if you are from the US or Canada, and have handheld FRS (Family Radio Service) or GMRS (General Mobile Radio Service) radios, you can't legally use these radios in Austria, as the frequencies used by these radios are already used by other services. (Austria has similar services, but they use different frequencies and you'd need to buy suitable radios locally.)

If your radios are truly Private Mobile Radio (specifically dPMR) and operate on the 446.1-446.2 MHz band, this may well be okay - you'd want to research specifically that they are permitted in Austria, but it seems they are. (You could not, however, use such radios in North America, as the 446 MHz band is reserved there for ham radio licensees only.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, I haven't mentioned that it's walkie-talkies that are operates at 446.0-446.1 MHz. I heard from a friend of mine about PMRs that they are allowed at all EU. According to your response I made a little research about legal usage of PMR spectrum at EU and I found a few documents about this kind of devices. First one is from [ECO](http://www.ero.dk/818B7698-2D99-431F-8D20-F41CA3B8AA56.W5Doc?frames=yes&) where it's fully legal to use and another one is [ECC Decision](http://www.erodocdb.dk/Docs/doc98/official/pdf/ECCDEC1505.PDF) with the same information.